# Ошибка unserialize()

Tags: php, ajax, сериализация

```
Message: unserialize()
[function.unserialize]: Error at
offset 0 of 57 bytes
```

Выдает такую ошибку при десериализации $_POST:

```
$formData = unserialize($_POST['formData']);
Сам *$_POST['formData']* содержит строку вида:

string(57) "name=Max&prenume=Popov&type=3&phone=32423424&code="
```

В чем подвох?

Comment: >В чем подвох? 

Это зависит от того, что вы хотите сделать?

На данный момент вы пытаетесь запихнуть в функцию не серилизованную строку и как и следовало это ожидать, получаете ошибку.

Comment: Хм, на стороне клиента сериализация так происходит:
    var formData  = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
    $.post('/registration/register', { formData : formData, add :      true } , function(response) {
     ShowMessage(response);
     });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На стороне сервера обрабатываете таким образом:

```
parse_str($_POST['formData'], $formData);
// $formData - будет содержать массив с данными
```

Answer (score 1):

```
name=Max&prenume=Popov&type=3&phone=32423424&code=
```

Это не серилизованная строка. Это по сути строка гет запроса (в случае в аяксом - пост запроса).

Серилизованная строка должна быть вида:

```
a:4:{s:6:"field1";s:4:"text";s:6:"field2";s:4:"text";i:0;i:3;i:1;s:5:"text4";}
```

Тогда функция unserialize() с ней справится

Comment: Да - это уже увидел, почему же var formData = $(this).closest('form').serialize(); не сериализует?

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, сериализует оно все нормально. Только в формат name=Max&prenume=Popov&type=3&phone=32423424&code= , а не такой как в пхп делает функция serialize()